# What are the factors to decide number of threads allowed for a python process?

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, python-2.7

Experts, i am facing an issue with my Pyspark (Spark 1.6/Python 2.7) code where i have an function to extract data, schema, counts etc from Hive tables and create local Linux files from it. Last month we changed it to run in threads because we had several tables to extract and didn't want it to go in a sequence. Doing so, we reduced extraction time from hours to mins since all table extracts now run in separate threads in parallel. It ran fine for couple of weeks no issues, and suddenly we started seeing few issues with it.

When i run this process certain times in a day, it executes perfectly, no issues. However, at certain times of day when i am trying to extract the table counts, schema details etc., it gives me errors-

In this example i am extracting source table count and saving it locally on Linux (need it for reconciliation purpose)

```
cat count_source_tableX.txt
Unable to determine Hadoop version information.
'hadoop version' returned:
# # There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue. # Cannot create GC thread. Out of system resources. # An error report file with more information is saved as: # /share/production/run/etl/hs_err_pid2760.log
```

This is the error when i tried to get schema of source hive table (using --showHeader=false --outputformat=csv2), these outputs are saved locally on Linux in my Pyspark code.

```
cat schema_src_tableX.txt
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
# Cannot create GC thread. Out of system resources.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /share/production/run/etl/hs_err_pid24841.log
```

Now, for sure, code doesn't have any issues, I have validated the same by running the same code in QA, UAT environments successfully , even in production when i run it at certain times, It can pull tables counts and schema without issue.

Why is the process not able to create new threads at certain times which i believe is causing these errors?

Thanks,
Sid

Comment: How long is a piece of string?  if you look at `ulimit -a` you can see per process limits; is there a possibility that the returned datasets fluctuate in size over the course of a day?  If no, you may need to investigate cgroups - how those are set-up will depend on the Linux distro you're using.

Comment: Can you post your multi-threading code part? @sidd

Comment: Thanks for your comments! i was able to debug it by limiting the threads to 5 at a time with Pool. Now i don't start all of them together and it resolved the issue for me!